# psycopg2 SELECT query with inbuilt functions

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I have the following SQL statement where i am reading the database to get the records for 1 day. Here is what i tried in pgAdmin console -

```
SELECT * FROM public.orders WHERE createdat >= now()::date AND type='t_order'
```

I want to convert this to the syntax of `psycopg2`but somehow it throws me errors -

```
Database connection failed due to invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "now()::date"
```

Here is what i am doing -

```
query = f"SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE (createdat>=%s AND type=%s)"
cur.execute(query, ("now()::date", "t_order"))
records = cur.fetchall()
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: You are passing the string 'now()::date' *as a string*, not as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **DO NOT** use `f` strings. Use proper [Parameter Passing](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries)
2. `now()::date` is better expressed as `current_date`. See [Current Date/Time](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT).
3. You want:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM public.orders WHERE (createdat>=current_date AND type=%s)"
cur.execute(query, ["t_order"])
```

If you want dynamic identifiers, table/column names then:

```
from psycopg2 import sql

query = sql.SQL("SELECT * FROM {} WHERE (createdat>=current_date AND type=%s)").format(sql.Identifier(table))

cur.execute(query, ["t_order"])
```

For more information see [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html).